# Select child for jQuery resizable alsoResize

Tags: jquery, resizable

I have an element that I'd like to resize, and I must resize the element beneath it at the same time.

jQuery resizable offers this feature with the `autoResize` option.
However, it requires you to provide a selector such as a class or id. If I provide a class, it will resize all elements on the page with that class. I would much rather provide a relative selector such as:

```
$(".panel").resizable({
  alsoResize: $(this).find(".panel-body")
});
```

But clearly `this` is not the `.panel` element I'm hoping for. Possibly a way around this would be to provide a `resize` function, such as:

```
$(".panel").resizable({
  resize: function(event, ui){ $(ui.element).find(".panel-body").css('width', $(ui.element).width() - (ui.originalSize.width - ui.element.width))}
});
```

But this just seems a bit ridiculous. Any suggestions?

Comment: P.S. there's a similar question that does not answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813859/jquery-resizable-how-to-select-child-for-alsoresize-property

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this  :

```
<div class="something"></div>
```

and in javascript , you can find it :

```
alsoResize: $(this).find(".something")
```

"Something" is whatever you like , you mustn't create it in css . It's useful with me

Comment: $(this) will not work inside of .resizable({}). 
find(".some-class") will work, but it will resize every class on the page.

Comment: You can give an unique class for that element . Whenever you find by that class , you can resize only it

Comment: Please read the question. I need to update a child of an object. There are multiple of these objects with children. If I come up with a unique class, then I would only be able to do one.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create a variable of the specific element you are trying to target.
If, for example, your target is a `<div id="targetDiv">`, create a variable using the following syntax:

`var $resizeTarget = $('div#targetDiv');`

Then add a random class to the element that will only be used for this specific purpose (no CSS applying necessary, although setting a `background-color` to it is advisable if only to make sure you are targeting that element only.)

`$resizeTarget.addClass('resizeTarget');`

From there, you can target that element by the class **OR** make another variable since you know it will be in the global name space.

`var $resizeTargetFinal = $('div.resizeTarget');`

Lastly, place this newly created variable in the function that automatically resizes.

`$(".panel").resizable({
  alsoResize: $resizeTargetFinal;
});`

**Option 2**

Use this function I created from the following link that allows for dynamic height change on resize. [Dynamic Height Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ojoevj1k/2/)

Comment: Hmmm I still have to create a unique id with this solution, or option 2 is make my own function. Still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I ended up using a custom function in the resize function temporarily. Here's a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ojoevj1k/4/

Comment: That is what I would recommend you do.  There is no reason why, when using other libraries that you should feel that you need to be rigid in your approach should said library not, out of the box, do what you need it to do.  There are vast ways to acheive whatever you want.  Outside of having the original author weigh in on a solution (which they would know the inner workings in more detail), but that may be only on his Github.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I was sort of hoping there might be a loop, that I can loop over my resizable elements and because I'm in a loop, have access to it inside resizable call. Or something clever like that.